# Access a function present in C# dll using Python

Tags: c#, python, .net, ctypes, dllimport

I want to access a function **my_function()** present in a c# file which is compiled into a .net dll - **abc.dll**.

**C# file**

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;


            namespace Test
            {
                public class Class1
                {
                    public string my_function()
                    {
                        return "Hello World.. :-";
                    }
                }
            }
```

After compiling the above code to abc.dll

**Using the below python trying to access my_function()**

```
            import ctypes
            lib = ctypes.WinDLL('abc.dll')
            print lib.my_function()
```

**Above code throws error**

> > > lib.my_function()
> > >                       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >                         File "", line 1, in 
> > >                         File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 378, in **getattr**
> > >                           func = self.**getitem**(name)
> > >                         File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 383, in **getitem**
> > >                           func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
> > >                       AttributeError: function 'my_function' not found

Comment: I'm guessing you should use the full function's namespace. Did you try  `print lib.Test.Class1.my_function()` ?

Comment: You have to make your .net dll COM visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't made the function visible in the DLL.

There are a few different ways you can do this.  The easiest is probably to use the [unmanagedexports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) package.  It allows you to call C# functions directly like normal C functions by decorating your function with [DllExport] attribute, like P/Invoke's DllImport.  It uses part of the subsystem meant to make C++/CLI mixed managed libraries work.

C# code

```
class Example
{
     [DllExport("ExampleFunction", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
     public static int ExampleFunction(int a, int b)
     {
         return a + b;
     } 
}
```

Python

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.WinDLL('example.dll')
print lib.ExampleFunction(12, 34)
```

Comment: Do I need to include and namespace for this, because even after including the DLLExport package getting  error - The type or namespace name 'DLLExport' could not be found.

Comment: You'll need to install the Unmanaged Exports package, either from the website I linked, or by finding the NuGet package under 'Project', then 'Manage NuGet Packages...'

Comment: Its still showing the same error - AttributeError: function 'ExampleFunction' not found

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. But that's now your problem to debug.