# C# DLL called from Python

Tags: python, c#, dll, class-library

I recently created a dll using a C# "Class Library" Project in Visual Studio. This project simply takes in input two integers and returns their sum; if I try to call this dll from a C# Winform App created in Visual Studio everything works fine, but now I'd like to call this dll from a Python3 script.

Here is my "CLass Library" dll:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DLLTest
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1
    {
        public int add(int n1, int n2)
        {
            return n1 + n2;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Python3 code:

```
from ctypes import *

mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\DLL path\mydll.dll')
result = mydll.add(3,5)
print(result)
```

But when I run the Python code it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\test_dll.py", line 5, in <module>
result = mydll.add(3,5)
File "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 369, in 
__getattr__
func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in 
__getitem__
func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'add' not found
```

I've already tried to launch python script as administrator but nothing changed. Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: This question is not about the Visual Studio application, so I've removed your `[visual-studio]` tag.

Comment: Would this answer help you @gorro1995? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569185/access-a-function-present-in-c-sharp-dll-using-python

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried making the function visible in the DLL with unmanagedexports package, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same approach from the python side, however this might help you - [Access a function present in C# dll using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569185/access-a-function-present-in-c-sharp-dll-using-python)

Comment: I've tried making the function visible in the DLL but still doesn't work....

Comment: Are you able to paste your updated code @gorro1995?