# Calling class library functions using python

Tags: python, c#, dll, ctypes

I have a class library created using C# with the following format.

```
namespace DateOperations
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public static String SAPDate(String Input){

}
```

the SAPDate being my function. How do I call the function using python?

I am facing challenges while using the package `ctypes` because its showing error as `cannot find function named SAPDate`

Code I used:

```
from ctypes import*
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\Users\Saeil LIlla\source\repos\DateOperations\DateOperations\bin\Debug\DateOperations.dll")
print(mydll)
result1= mydll.DateOperations.SAPDate("4-Jul-22")
print("Date Value value:"+result1)
```

The Function is to return a formatted string

Comment: Does this answer help at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569185/access-a-function-present-in-c-sharp-dll-using-python

Comment: Alternatively, it seems like there's [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)