# How do I load a DLL via Python in Raspbian?

Tags: python, c#, dll, raspberry-pi

Currently I am in the process of writing a GUI in Python for a Raspberry Pi.

However, it needs to access a large amount of methods from a DLL.

I have access to the DLL's .cs code but don't exactly know what to do with it. Do I need to create a .so file?

I already used the Python.NET package to successfully load the library into my Python script under Windows.

How do I make the step so I can use it in Raspbian?

Comment: If the functions in the DLL aren't meant for reuse they may not be DLLExport. If they are then this might work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569185/access-a-function-present-in-c-sharp-dll-using-python